# Order calculation program created with JavaScript does not work

Tags: javascript

```js
let americano = 0;
let cafelatte = 0;
let icechocolate = 0;
let yourMoney = 0;
let totalCost = 0;
let change = 0;
let changeList = [1000, 500, 100, 50, 10];
let voidList = [];

function calculate() {
    americano = 3000 * Number(prompt("how many americano"));
    cafelatte = 5000 * Number(prompt("how many cafelatte"));
    icechocolate = 500 * Number(prompt("how many icechocolate"));
    totalCost = americano + cafelatte + icechocolate;
    yourMoney = Number(prompt("How much do you have"));
    change = Number(yourMoney - totalCost);
    if(change > 0){
        for (let i = 0; i < changeList.length; i++) {
            voidList[i].push(Number(change/changeList[i]));
            change = change - (changeList[i])*(change/changeList[i]);
        }
    }
    else if(change < 0){
        init()
    }
}
function info(){
        document.write("1000 " + voidList[0] + " won");
        document.write("500 " + voidList[1] + " won");
        document.write("100 " + voidList[2] + " won");
        document.write("50 " + voidList[3] + " won");
        document.write("10 " + voidList[4] + " won");
}
function init(){    
    calculate();
    info();
}
init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

It is a program that asks how many Americano cafe latte ice chocolate you will order, receives money, and gives change.
But Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. There's an error.
How can I solve it and make a complete code?

Comment: `let voidList = [];` You never put any items in the array, so `voidList[i]` will not be an array you can `.push` to

Comment: You probably meant `voidList.push()` instead?

Comment: Note: if `change` is negative, your program's behavior is very poor (indirect recursive calls to `calculate()` with re-prompt for every single item).

Comment: Yes! I thought i could make an empty arrangement and put it in, but I guess i can't.

Comment: You can put items into an empty array. You just can't specify the index value `[i]` unless the specified index already exists. Simply use `voidList.push()` without the `[i]`. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `[i]` from `voidList[i]`. You can push without specifying an index. This will work:

```js
let americano = 0;
let cafelatte = 0;
let icechocolate = 0;
let yourMoney = 0;
let totalCost = 0;
let change = 0;
let changeList = [1000, 500, 100, 50, 10];
let voidList = [];

function calculate() {
    americano = 3000 * Number(prompt("how many americano"));
    cafelatte = 5000 * Number(prompt("how many cafelatte"));
    icechocolate = 500 * Number(prompt("how many icechocolate"));
    totalCost = americano + cafelatte + icechocolate;
    yourMoney = Number(prompt("How much do you have"));
    change = Number(yourMoney - totalCost);
    console.log(change);
    if(change > 0){
        for (let i = 0; i < changeList.length; i++) {
            voidList.push(Number(change/changeList[i]));
            change = change - (changeList[i])*(change/changeList[i]);
        }
    }
    else if(change < 0){
        init()
    }
}
function info(){
        document.write("1000 " + voidList[0] + " won<br>");
        document.write("500 " + voidList[1] + " won<br>");
        document.write("100 " + voidList[2] + " won<br>");
        document.write("50 " + voidList[3] + " won<br>");
        document.write("10 " + voidList[4] + " won");
}
function init(){    
    calculate();
    info();
}
init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```